# Quasi affine scheme universal embedding

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Suppose $X$ is quasi affine scheme, it is well known that it open embeds in $Y=\mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}(X))$. In fact, by adjunction, any map into an affine scheme factors uniquely through $Y$. Is it true that for any open embedding $X \to Z$, $Z$ affine, the induced map $Y \to Z$ is open embedding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true. Consider $X=\Bbb A^2\setminus (0,0)$, so that $Y=\Bbb A^2$. Let $Z$ be the union of the $xy$-plane and the $z$-axis inside $\Bbb A^3$. Then $X\hookrightarrow Z$ by $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y,0)$ is an open embedding, but the induced map $Y\to Z$ does not have open image.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if $Y \to Z$ has to be an immersion?

Comment: No, here's a contrived counterexample. Consider $X$ as two disjoint copies of the affine plane without the origin mapping in to $Z=\Bbb A^4$ where the first copy maps to $(x,y,0,0)$ and the second copy maps to $(0,0,z,w)$. Then the two origins in $Y$ both map to the origin in $Z$ and it's not injective.

Comment: (Sorry, $Z$ should be the union of the two planes $V(x,y)$ and $V(z,w)$ in the previous post - I goofed and now it's too late to edit.)